# NLog: Using variables in included configuration file

Tags: .net, nlog

I'm currently trying to distribute my NLog configuration over separated configuration files which are being included by a "master" configuration.

In the master I'm defining variables which I would like to reuse in the included configuration.

Consider this as master being defined in the *.exe.config*:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
  </configSections>

  <nlog autoReload="true" keepVariablesOnReload="true" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <variable name="log_dir" value="./" />
    <include file="~/Workers.NLog.config" />
  </nlog>
```

The included *Workers.NLog.config* looks like this:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwExceptions="true">

  <variable name="verbose" value="${longdate}|${processid}|${level}|${logger}|${message}${onexception:|EXCEPTION OCCURRED\:${exception:format=toString,Data}}" />

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="all" fileName="${log_dir}/all.log" layout="${verbose}" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="all" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

This results in an exception saying: **LayoutRenderer cannot be found: 'log_dir'**

What am I missing?

Comment: Check your internal log (trace level): https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging. It should work

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I found the problem.
In another location of the fairly huge config *.exe.config was a *Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter defined which was configured to load the file *Workers.NLog.config directly without considering the variables from *.exe.config. So of course the vars from there weren't defined.